# Passing Value to create initial value in form

Tags: django, forms

I am trying to create a center of a project (foreign key).

However, when I call the url to create a center the project which this center should belong to is not automaticly set. So the user has to choose the project.

The goal is to prefill the form element 'Project' with the name of the Project the id of which is specified in the url, the last element of the url is the id of the project as seen here: `http://192.168.10.84:8080/procure/centercreate/5`

Therefore I have to look up the name of the project with id 5, fill the form element and make it none editable.

what I have so far:

#### model of center:

```py
class Center(models.Model):
    CenterName = models.CharField(max_length=60, null=False)
    Project = models.ForeignKey(Project,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.CenterName
```

### url.py

```py
path('centercreate/<int:pk>', views.CenterCreate.as_view(), name='center_create'),
```

### views.py

````py
class CenterCreate(CreateView):
    model = Center
    form_class = CenterCreateForm
    template_name = 'Procure/center_create.html'
    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('centers_sys', kwargs={'pk':self.object.Project_id})

## connected form I use:

```py
class CenterCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
       model = Center
       fields = "__all__"
````

### template used:

```html
{% extends "base_generic.html" %}
{% block content %}
<div id="container" >
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
    <p>Welcome to ProcEdu - developed by <em>BZG</em>!</p>
    <h3>You are adding a Center to Project: <!-- PROJECT -->> </h3>
    <div id="content-main">
        <form method="post" action=""  >  
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.errors }}
        <!--   {{ form.Project2 }}  -->
        <table>
            <div class="form-row">
                <tr> 
          <!-- this field I would like to have set with the ProjectName and not editable -->
                    <td>{{ form.Project.label_tag }}</td>
                    <td>{{ form.Project }} </td>
                </tr>
            </div>
            <div class="form-row">
                <tr> 
                    <td>{{ form.CenterName.label_tag }}</td>
                    <td>{{ form.CenterName }}</td>
                </tr>
            </div>
            <div class="submit-row">
                <tr><td><input type="submit" value="Submit"></td></tr>
            </div>
            </table>
        </form>
        </div>
      </div>
{% else %}
<a href="{% url 'login' %}?next={{ request.path}}">Login</a>
{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

I would be grateful for any help

Answer (score 0):

This is a fairly "easy" to do; just a bit difficult to find. Follow me here: 
The [`CreateView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.CreateView) is utilizing the [`FormMixin`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#formmixin). If you want to pass static initial data, you can do so via [`initial`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormMixin.initial). If you want to pass dynamic initial data you want to use the [`get_initial()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormMixin.get_initial) method.

```py
class CenterCreate(CreateView):
   model = Center
   form_class = CenterCreateForm
   template_name = 'Procure/center_create.html'

   def get_success_url(self):
      return reverse('centers_sys', kwargs={'pk':self.object.Project_id})

   def get_initial(self):
      qs = Project.objects.get( project_id = self.kwargs['pk'] )
      initial = {'project': qs}
      return initial
```

So far so good. If you want to set that field to [`disabled`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/forms/fields/#disabled) you can implement that to the `__init__`method of your form.

```py
class CenterCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['project'].disabled = True

    class Meta:
       model = Center
       fields = "__all__"
```

Let me know how this works for you! Please check out the provided links - maybe you need to do some adjustments.

Comment: Hello Tarquinius,
thanks a lot. With small adjustments I got it running and delivering the results I was looking for.
I will definitely look into the links you provided!
Ben